# Can't run AVD in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

This list of errors show up everytime I try:

> Cannot launch AVD in emulator. Output: emulator: WARNING: VM heap size
>   set below hardware specified minimum of 384MB emulator: WARNING:
>   Setting VM heap size to 384MB emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently
>   requires hardware acceleration! Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly
>   installed and usable. CPU acceleration status: Android Emulator
>   requires an Intel processor with VT-x and NX support.  (VT-x is not
>   supported)

Please explain to me what to do about this, thank you.

Comment: Could you show us some of the code you're attempting to run in the emulator?

Comment: Make sure you have VT-x enabled in BIOS / Set-up, what CPU do you have ?

Answer (score 0):

VT-x means Intel Virtualization Technology.

I think your CPU doesn't support VT-x Technology.

Here is [List of VT-x Supported Cpu in Intel](http://ark.intel.com/Products/VirtualizationTechnology)

Check your computer specifications.